# Printing WebView content in Android app cuts off on the right side

Tags: android, printing, webview

I'm using the code described on [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs) to print the content of a WebView.

```
PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";

PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = myWebView.createPrintDocumentAdapter(jobName);

PrintJob printJob = printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter, new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
```

The App runs on a tablet (landscape). The printed content however is cut off on the right side. I post 2 images below. The first one is a portion of the actual WebView content (the table below the chart has 8 columns).

[image]

---

The second image is a portion of the printed doc. As you can see the table misses the last column and the search field is also cut. Is there a way to adapt the page so it fits into an A4-sized sheet?

[image]